# Multiple extend blocks

Tags: node.js, pug, template-engine

So I'm using jade to build a couple of webpages, but my landingpage differs in the other pages in the way that it hasn't got a menu. Except for that it shares the same header and footer. My problem is that I'd like to conditionally include menu.jade into conversion to html. I'd like to do something like this:

base.jade:

```
doctype html
  head
    title= title
  body
    block menu
    block content
    include footer
```

menu.jade

```
extends base
  ul
    li Home
    li Contact
```

index.jade:

```
extends base
block content
  p hello landingpage
```

page.jade

```
extends base
block content
  p hello subpage
```

The thing is: when I convert index.jade everything is fine; my pages looks like I want it to. But when I convert page.jade I somehow would like to include menu.jade as well,o I don't have to rewrite my menu across all subpages.

Answer (score 0):

menu.jade

```
ul
   li Home
   li Contact
```

page.jade

```
extends base
block menu
   include menu
block content
   p hello subpage
```

anotherpage.jade

```
extends page
block content
   p hello another page
```